# Getting into Fk Table to update records

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I dont really know how to explain this or if the title is ok , but here goes

I have two tables :

```
Table Person
id name last_name

Table User
id username pw person_id(fk)
```

So i have a relation in user to person , how would be a query to update "Name" on Person , like in a single query

~On the method i would do , is using the user id to find the person_id then use person_id and look for it on the table then edit it , yet i hope there is a optimal way to do that , prob with Inner join , yet i still dont get inner join so much

Comment: check [mysql inner join update](http://www.voidtricks.com/mysql-inner-join-update/)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
Update persons set name='new name' Where person_id=(select person_id where userid=5)
```

And convert it into joins when you master them.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all :)

This worked for me

```
UPDATE person INNER JOIN user ON user.person_id = person.id SET name='$name' WHERE user.id='$get_id'
```